# Adding random number to itself in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am generating a random number on click in jQuery. At the end of this post, you can see the code that I am working with.

Is there a way where every time a new random number gets generated it gets added to the old one in a variable called `totalRandomNumbers`?

I want to do it for all three variables `random`, `random_0`, `random_1`.

```js
$("#reset").click(function(){
           var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12);
           var random_0 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12);
           var random_1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12);

           $("#push0").html(random);
           $("#push1").html(random_0);
           $("#push2").html(random_1);
           $('input[name="hamPush"]').val($("#push0").html());
           $('input[name="zikPush"]').val($("#push1").html());
           $('input[name="musPush"]').val($("#push2").html());      
})
```

Comment: show us your code too?

Comment: added the value of random number or just keeping the count of generation??

Comment: no not the count of generation, I want to add the numbers which are generated.

Comment: *Is there a way where every time a new random number gets generated it gets added to the old one in a variable called `totalRandomNumbers`?* How about every time you generate a new random number, you add it to a variable called `totalRandomNumbers`? Just a thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the start of your JavaScript, make a variable:

```
var totalRandomNumbers = 0;
```

And when you generate your random number, add it to the variable.

```
totalRandomNumbers += (code to generate random number)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var randomSum = 0;
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
};

function sumRandom() {
 randomSum += getRandomInt(1, 100)
};

$('.genRandomButton').on('click', function() {
    console.log(randomSum)
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Just tried in browser console:

```js
var _totalRandomNumbers = 0;

Object.defineProperty(window, "totalRandomNumbers", {
    get: function() { return _totalRandomNumbers += Math.random(); }
});

console.log(totalRandomNumbers);
console.log(totalRandomNumbers);
```

and so on :-)

You can do anything in get accessor, store old values etc.